# Modulo operation for integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new in Python. I just wonder, is there a modulo operation (%) exclusive for integers? My interest focuses into large (number of digits ~ 10^9) integers.

Appreciate any help.
Erwin

Comment: The modulus operator in python works as modulus integer operation as long as it is fed in integers.  eg: `1234567890%1000 == 890` works fine in python.  Just make sure integers go in or it will use whichever point modulus operation makes sense based on input.

Comment: Assuming you are generating the numbers via exponentiation (I'm not sure how you generate a billion-digit number in any reasonable amount of time otherwise), you probably want to look at the 3-argument form of the `pow` function.

Answer (score 2):

The default modulo is ok for any kind of bigint. And the python3 int and python2 long are bigint by default.

If you are worrying about performance, it is also ok because python check the types of operands and call the correct version of modulo. You can call int to int mod by this way:

```py
(10).__mod__(3)
```

which is just same to below except for type checking:

```py
10 % 3
```

In this case, the problem is mostly the digits. 10^9 digits are not fit to design of python bigint. So it will take really long time.